# How can I play DAE animation from a specific time interval in ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

My animation model has a total time interval of 45 seconds. I tap on the model and should be able to play it not right from the beginning, but from say, the 15th second.

Can anyone please help me out if you think by any means that this is possible?

**EDIT:**

As soon as I load my animation model, the SceneKit plays the animation. Now with the key in hand, I crop the animation with the help of a custom method I came across.

By tapping on the model, I enumerate through all the parent/child nodes to stop or remove animation from the scene. So far so good.

The problem appears when I try to add the cropped animation back on to the scene. Nothing really happens, as the scene remains idle without any action.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: sceneView)

    // Let's test if a 3D Object was touch
    var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption: Any]()
    hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly] = true

    let hitResults: [SCNHitTestResult] = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: hitTestOptions)

    let animation = animScene?.entryWithIdentifier("myKey", withClass: CAAnimation.self)
    print(" duration is...", animation!.duration)

    let animationNew = subAnimation(of:(animation)!, startFrame: 10, endFrame: 360)
    print("New duration is...", animationNew.duration)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        node.removeAllAnimations()
    }
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        node.addAnimation(animationNew, forKey: "myKey")
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, it's the most robust approach for playing animations containing in `Collada` file:

```
import SceneKit

func myAnimation(path: String) -> SCNAnimation? {

    let scene = SCNScene(named: path)
    var animation: SCNAnimationPlayer?

    scene?.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes( { (child, stop) in
        if let animationKey = child.animationKeys.first {

            animation = child.animationPlayer(forKey: animationKey)

            // variable pointee: ObjCBool { get nonmutating set }
            stop.pointee = true
        }
    })
    return animation?.animation
}

let node = SCNNode()
let animation = myAnimation(path: "animation.dae")
node.addAnimation(animation!, forKey: "FirstAnimationSet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems my .dae file had a number of animations(with multiple id's) and they should be grouped as one. Once I group them together, I get control over the animation and  could play them from whichever frame I want.